# Detect MimeType of an image

Tags: http, https, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

`https://qa4-sprcdn-assets.sprinklr.com/400002/fd08262c-bb86-417d-a4af-21f9775fb08a-321679353.png`

This image has extension as png but originally its mimeType is image/avif.

Its image extension was changed from avif to png (only extension was changed) and then uploaded to cloud and then this is that cloud url.

I want to know is there any way to get the original mimeType (image/avif) from this url.

Tried fetching its content type from http request, that also shows image/png.

Comment: You can download it and run `file` on it. To solve this programmatically, look for `libmagic` bindings for whichever programming language you are using. This is probably a duplicate.